# Using Bootstrap Growl Message in a JSF application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, bootstrap-notify

I would like to use Bootstrap Growl Message like this one  https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-growl in my JSF project, but I don't know how to config it. I want it to be showed when an action finished (it should return fail or success).

Answer (score 1):

I wish I would have noticed this ealier. If you are still using my plugin here is how you would call it.

You can also find documentation and examples on my plugin at the [Bootstrap Growl Website](http://bootstrap-growl.remabledesigns.com/) (Latest Version)

If using version 1.0.6 and wanting to display just a message.

```
var request = $.ajax({...});

request.done(function( msg ) {
    $.growl('Successful', { type: 'success' });
}); 

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    $.growl({ title: 'Request failed: ', message: textStatus }, { type: 'success' });
});
```

If using version 2.0.0 (Just released yesterday) and wanting to display message. In this new version you can update the growl.

```
var growl = $.growl({ 
                    title: 'Please Wait... ', 
                    message: 'Updating Database'
                },{
                    type: 'info',
                    allow_dismiss: false,
                    delay: 0
                }),
    request = $.ajax({...});
request.done(function( msg ) {
    // Update growl with success info
    growl.update('title', 'Success ');
    growl.update('message', 'Your changes have been saved');
    growl.update('type', 'success');
    // Since we disabled both the dismiss and delay we have to close
    // the growl manually. This closes it after 5 seconds. 
    setInterval(function() {
            growl.close();
    }, 5000);
}); 

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    // Update growl with failed info
    growl.update('title', 'Request failed: ');
    growl.update('message', textStatus);
    growl.update('type', 'danger');
    // Since we disabled both the dismiss and delay we have to close
    // the growl manually. This closes it after 5 seconds.  
    setInterval(function() {
            growl.close();
    }, 5000);
});
```